# Use of undeclared variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def fi(n):
    print(counter)
    data = counter + 1
    return data


counter = 2
print(fi(10))
```

How can this code work well?? 
I guess this code doesn't work well because of `counter`
in `fi()`function, there's no declaration of `counter`...

Comment: `counter` will look for a local variable, if it doesn't find one, it looks for the variable in any enclosing scopes, then finally, in the global scope. So yes, this will work.

Comment: shouldn't you you substitute `counter` for `n`?

Comment: What is the purpose or context of this function/code? Are you intending that `fi` increases the counter by 1 regardless of the value of `n`? Were you meaning to increase it by `n`? Were you intending to use `n` at all?

Comment: thank you ~~~ i catch it

Answer (score 0):

You are mis-using the counter variable; to keep your function pure, just use n in the function, e.g.:

```
def fi(n):
    print(n)
    data = n + 1
    return data


counter = 2
print(fi(counter))
```

Comment: i know i'm misusing but a point is counter can work well even if there's no declaration  in fi()function

Comment: So, if it's out of scope you cannot use it; if it's in scope; you can use it. If you want to change it assign the output of the function to the variable: this is how it works.